# Как вывести константный итераторный тип из данного

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть шаблонный класс примерно такого вида:

```
template<typename I>
class Foo
{
   const I Begin   ;
   const I End     ;
         I Position;

public:
   bool append(const I begin, const I end)
   {
       if(std::distance(begin, end) <= std::distance(Position, End))
       {
           Position = std::copy(begin,end,Position);
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
};
```

Следующий ниже код не компилируется, так как `const I` для `append` выводится в `int * const`, а не в желаемый `cosnt int *` получающийся из `std::begin(data)` и `std::end(data)`:

```
auto foo = Foo<int *>(/* как-то инициализируем */); 
const int data[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
foo.append(  std::begin(data)
           , std::end  (data) );
```

Пока что я решил эту задачу так:

```
template<typename U>
bool append(U begin, U end)
{
    //... здесь так же
}
```

Но все рано остался вопрос, как вывести из `I` равного `int *` нужный `cont int *`? Кроме того, желательно чтобы решение учитывало что `I` может быть стандартным `iterator` и выводило бы его в `const_iterator`.

Comment: @Abyx Потому что в `append` выполняется копирование данных во-первых, во-вторых если будет `bool append(I begin, I end)` пример с `data` тоже не скомпилируется.

Comment: @Abyx `std::copy` для примера, не про нее вопрос, а про вывод типов.

Comment: Обращаю внимание, что константный итератор и итератор по константному массиву - это принципиально разные вещи (так же, как и с указателями). Константный итератор (`const vector::iterator`) - это итератор, который менять нельзя, но можно менять значение, на которое он указывает. Итератор по константным элементам (`vector::const_iterator`) менять можно, но нельзя менять элементы, на которые он указывает. Например, итератор по константному вектору `const vector x;` - это только `const_iterator`.

Answer (score 1):

Ваше решение с шаблонизацией метода `append` в некотором смысле более верное и более общее, чем попытки как-то хитро сконструировать добавить константность внутрь указателя:

```
template<typename U>
bool append(U begin, U end)
{
    //... здесь так же
}
```

Проблема возникает не просто из-за константности, а из-за того, что если мы не шаблонизируем `append`, то мы сильно и непонятно зачем ограничиваем множество типов, которые можно приписать к `Foo`. Например, с одной стороны, в переменную типа `int` всегда можно записать `char`, однако вызвать `append(char*, char*)` не получится, что не слишком хорошо. Получается, `append` менее мощный, чем простой оператор присваивания, что не очень хорошо.

`const int` - это лишь частный случай: переменную `int` можно проинициализировать из `const int`, поэтому `append` должен, в частности, принимать параметры типов `const int*`.

Если вы шаблонизируете `append`, то серьёзных дополнительных ограничений у вас не появляется: класс и так шаблонный, поэтому он и так должен быть целиком реализован в заголовочном файле. Стало быть, любой его метод можно безболезненно также сделать шаблонным.

Comment: Правильный подход не в том чтобы убирать ограничения,а в том чтобы ими управлять и таким образом структурировать код. Собственно из этого и вытекает мой вопрос. И в данном случае я хочу ограничить тип параметров, чтоб нельзя было передать что угодно. Потому, что если соглашаешься на что угодно, то и готовым надо быть к чему угодно, а это трудно.

Comment: @Cerbo так ведь у вас код уже и так готов к чему угодно? Если хотите, чтобы ваш метод можно было вызвать лишь с очень ограниченным набором типов - добавьте, пожалуйста, точное описание этого набора в вопрос (скажем, "всё, у чего есть `iterator_traits`") и желаемый эффект от вызова с типом не из этого набора ("произвольная ошибка компиляции"/"читаемая ошибка компиляции").

Comment: Поясню и вам, вопрос не про использование, а про вывод типа. Если `I`, нужно получить правильный `const I`

Answer (score 0):

Решение для C++11. Это не универсальное решение, но для типов с указателем (наподобие int*) работает. Нужно добавить в класс using и изменить метод append:

```
    using T = typename std::add_pointer<
        typename std::add_const<
            typename std::remove_pointer<I>::type >
    ::type >::type;

    bool append(T begin, T end)
    ...
```

Для случая int* происходит следующее:
1. В начале убираем из переданного типа I указатель (remove_pointer), получаем int.
2. Далее добавляем ему константность (add_const), получаем const int.
3. Добавляем указатель (add_pointer), получаем const int*.

Для универсального решения можно посмотреть на std::is_pointer, так как действия выше нужны только для типа указателя.

Comment: Как быть с контейнерными итераторами?

Answer (score 0):

Вот что сам придумал, использовав сопоставление с образоцом при частичной специализации:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>

template<class T>
struct is_const_iterator
     : std::is_const<std::iterator_traits<T>::reference>
{};

// для интераторов STL
template<class T>
struct iterator_traits_ex: std::iterator_traits<T>
{
    typedef T                 original_iterator;
    //typedef /* не известно */        iterator;
    //typedef /* не известно */  const_iterator;
};

template<class T>
struct iterator_traits_ex<T *>: std::iterator_traits<T*>
{
    typedef       T * original_iterator;
    typedef       T *          iterator;
    typedef const T *    const_iterator;
};

template<class T>
struct iterator_traits_ex<const T *>: std::iterator_traits<const T *>
{
    typedef const T * original_iterator;
    typedef       T *          iterator;
    typedef const T *    const_iterator;
};
```

Подстановка выполняется при специализации для указателей (последние два варианта). Решения для стандартных итераторов STL так же не придумал пока, но зато теперь ругаюсь static_assert'ом если итератор константный подставили.

Использовать это следует вот так:

```
template<typename I>
class Foo
{
   static_assert(!is_const_iterator<I>::value, "Type of I can't be a const iterator!");

   // ...

   typedef typename iterator_traits_ex<I>::const_iterator ConstIterator;       
public:
   bool append(ConstIterator begin, ConstIterator end)
   {
      // ...
   }
};
```